# Manjaro - Windows 10 dual-boot, Windows not found

Tags: windows-10, multi-boot, grub, manjaro

I used to happily run Debian Buster and Windows 10 on dual-boot. I decided to move from Debian to Manjaro.

During the Manjaro install process, I tried just using the Debian partition when the installer asked me to select a partition where to install Manjaro.

The installation failed when setting up grub.

When I rebooted, I got the grub rescue screen, and not knowing how to handle it, I rebooted again into the Manjaro live usb to re-do the install process.

There, I manually repartitionned, choosing the partition with the failed Manjaro installation as a mount point for / and chosing the old /boot partition as a mount point for /boot/efi (the installer told me that I needed a partition for /boot/efi

And finally, the installation went smoothly.

But in the end, when I boot the computer, it won't even show the grub screen and directly boots into Manjaro.

**What I tried:**

```bsh
# os-prober
```

No response

```bsh
# update-grub
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found theme: /usr/share/grub/themes/manjaro/theme.txt
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.6-x86_64
Found initrd image: /boot/amd-ucode.img /boot/initramfs-5.6-x86_64.img
Found initrd fallback image: /boot/initramfs-5.6-x86_64-fallback.img
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+/memtest.bin
done
```

```bsh
# ls /boot/
amd-ucode.img  efi  grub  initramfs-5.6-x86_64-fallback.img  initramfs-5.6-x86_64.img  linux56-x86_64.kver  memtest86+  vmlinuz-5.6-x86_64
```

```bsh
# ls /boot/efi/
EFI
```

```bsh
# ls /boot/efi/EFI/
boot  Manjaro
```

**Assumption:** I think I overwrote something from the 500MiB partition where I should be able to boot into Windows 10, and the system won't be detected.

The Windows 10 files are still in their partition.

**Question:**
What should I add into the /boot partition to make grub detect windows 10?

Comment: `/boot` is irrelevant, it's Linux-only. `/boot/efi` is the mount point of EFI System Partition and there are two directories (with contents) missing there: `EFI\Microsoft` and `EFI\Boot`.

Comment: @gronostaj so that's what I overwrote on?

Comment: I guess you've formatted it accidentally. Normally the installer would add its bootloader to that partition.

Comment: would repairing windows from a bootable windows installer put them back in?

Comment: I'm not sure. I think it didn't work for me in the past. There are tutorials on the Internet how to restore this partition.